# Can marathon register to multiple mesos?

Tags: mesos, marathon

Marathon and Mesos do not support muti-datacenter. We are trying to find a way go around it. Can we run mesos in each data centersand have marathon talk to all the mesos from difference data centers?

Answer (score 0):

So far marathon only could use one Mesos Master. Maybe you could combine your Mesos clusters to a big Mesos cluster.

Comment: Thanks again Michael. Does Mesos support multi-datacenter then?